# Starting a new session causes Error - Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

When starting a new session, for example when I access localhost from an incognito tab, I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at done (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:10)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:261:5)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:461:10)
    at View.render (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:113:20
    at tryHandleCache (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:261:5)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:461:10)
    at View.render (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\Documents\Projects\TypeTest\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
```

I am aware that calling `res.render()` or `res.send()` etc. multiple times causes this error, but I cannot find any example of this in my code. As I mentioned, this only happens when starting a brand new session (I think), for example when accessing the site in an incognito tab. This leads me to believe it has something to do with cookie-session maybe re-rendering the page?

Even when I leave the `get` router completely empty and no information is ever sent, I get the same error. Once again this leads me to believe it has something to do with my session middleware. I am also using Passport for authentication, but I don't think that this is causing the issue.

Here is part of `server.js` that includes the session middleware.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('layout', 'layouts/default')
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const flash = require('express-flash');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

app.use(flash());
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  maxAge: 10000000 * 60 * 60 * 24
}));

const passport = require('passport');
const initializePassport = require('./config/passport');
initializePassport(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Here is my Passport config. file

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
      User.findOne().byEmailOrUsername(email).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' })
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          } else if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' });
          }
        });
      })
    }));

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log('serialize');
    return done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log('deserialize');

    return User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  });
}
```

Apologies if this question is too loosely worded, but I am very unsure of what is causing this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed

Before I was redirecting HTTP requests to a HTTPS server using

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.protocol === 'http') {
    res.redirect(301, `https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`);
  }
  next();
})
```

This caused any HTTP requests to be handled twice. I was only experiencing this when using an incognito tab because in a regular tab, Chrome automatically switches to HTTPS before making the request. Fixed by doing

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.protocol === 'http') {
    res.redirect(301, `https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`);
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
  return done(err, user);
});
```

});

You can not use return statement into a return statement because there is only return statement. !!!

Comment: Nope, tried using arrow functions too. Using only one return statement does not fix the issue.